# Total logic / data decoupling with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, design-patterns, orm, model, sqlalchemy

I am trying (purely as an exercice) to build a graphical software able to draw some charts representing Market data and doing some simple analysis.

I am using Python3.5 + SQLAlchemy1.1 for persistence (and PyQt but not relevant here).

To make it simple, I want to have a class 'Stock' representing a trading stock and a class 'Exchange' representing a market exchange (Paris market, London market, etc.). Each Stock has a Market.

By using [Declarative Mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping), this would give the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Exchange(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'exchange'

    ticker = Column(String(2), primary_key=True)
    name   = Column(String(20))

class Stock(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'stock'

    ticker          = Column(String(5), primary_key=True)
    exchange_ticker = Column('exchange', String(2), ForeignKey('exchange.ticker'),
                             primary_key=True)
    name            = Column(String(20), unique=True)

    exchange = relationship(Exchange)
```

But as I said, this is purely an exercice, and I would like to make it more 'decoupled': I would like to **totally** separate the 'business logic' from the 'persistence layer' (I am using quotes because I see these expressions everywhere and I think I got their meaning, but I am not a professional developer so I may not see the whole thing).

Ultimately, I would like to separate the business logic and the persistence layer in 2 modules (or packages, same), potentially 'gitsubmoduling' them, and be able to install and launch the logic module **without any persistence** (without even installing sqlalchemy / psycopg2 for PostgreSQL, etc.). This is a good practice, or at least a good objective, right?

So I had a deeper look at SQLAlchemy doc and I found the concept of [Classical Mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings) (automatically handled by Declarative Mapping). This would gives:

core.py (purely logic, possibly functional without any persistence)

```
class Exchange:

    def __init__(self, ticker: str, name: str):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.name = name

class Stock:

    def __init__(self, ticker: str, exchange: Exchange, name: str=None):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.exchange = exchange
        self.name = name

    # Some business logic: correlations, data analysis, etc.
```

model.py (mapping logic to database)

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, MetaData, String, Table, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper

from core import Exchange, Stock

metadata = MetaData()

stock = Table(
    'stock', metadata,
    Column('ticker',   String(5), primary_key=True),
    Column('exchange', String(2), ForeignKey('exchange.ticker'), primary_key=True),
    Column('name',     String(20))
)

exchange = Table(
    'exchange', metadata,
    Column('ticker', String(2), primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(20))
)

mapper(Stock, stock)
mapper(Exchange, exchange)
```

This does not work: when I try to insert some fixtures:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: 'INSERT INTO stock (ticker, name, exchange) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('CAC', None, <core.Exchange object at 0x108bd0fd0>)]
```

As you can see, he tries to 'insert' an Exchange object directly. Therefore, I tried (with different options and configs):

```
mapper(Stock, stock, properties={
    'exchange': relationship(Exchange)
})
```

But SQLAlchemy raises an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: WARNING: when configuring property 'exchange' on Mapper|Stock|stock, column 'exchange' conflicts with property '<RelationshipProperty at 0x1096d5cf8; exchange>'.
```

It seems that whatever I try (I tried a lot of other stuffs, with `exclusive_properties`, naming the `relationship`, etc.) SQLAlchemy wants a relationship object in my Stock (which makes sense..). So I am wondering is that level of decoupling is really reachable.

My questions are:

- Am I missing something obvious?
- Am I wrong to want that level of 'decoupling'?
- Am I facing the [Object-relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) which is referenced in some places (as [here](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/12/01/orm-offensive-anti-pattern.html), [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120321/is-orm-an-anti-pattern) or [here](http://seldo.com/weblog/2011/08/11/orm_is_an_antipattern))?

Comment: You should rename your column from `exchange` to `exchange_ticker` and  use the relationship as you declared it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it worked, thanks. Sorry to be annoying, but would you know any way to keep the name `exchange`?

Comment: You certainly can have two dogs with the same name, but that would be very confusing for dogs. And it is not possible to have two variables with the same name in the same scope in any programming language (i know of).
So you either use `exchange` for the column containing "ticker" value (in which case you need to pick different name for the relationship to actual `Exchange`), or you use `exchange` for the relationship, but then rename the column to be `exchange_ticker`. The latter is the most chosen option in my practice